# PHP OOP :: holding config 'global' values accessible to all classes

Tags: php, oop, factory, global

I am using a Factory class to manage the instantiation of objects and am passing into their constructors any dependency objects  (Dependency Injection) e.g.

```
function createBasket() {
    //pass in dependent objects
    $apiCon = $this->createAPIConnector($this);
    $basket = new Basket($this, $apiCon);
    return $basket;
}
```

I am trying to avoid using the 'new' keyword within any classes (other than Factory), to allow simpler and more robust unit test, clearer code etc.

Now, my question relates to configuration values that many classes require e.g.

```
$apiURL = 'http://some.api.com';
$apiKey = 'abcde12345';
$adminEmail = 'someone@site.com';
```

These values remain constant for each application instance. I currently have them in a singleton class Config and they are reachable from within any class by the following:

```
$cfg = Config::getInstance();
$address = $cfg->apiURL;
```

However, this class instance is still a dependency within any Class that calls it, so should I think about passing this into class constructors, e.g.

```
function createBasket() {
    //pass in dependent objects
    $apiCon = $this->createAPIConnector($this);
    $cfg = Config::getInstance();
    //pass singleton config object to constructor
    $basket = new Basket($this, $apiCon, $cfg);
    return $basket;
}
```

...or perhaps pass them in via a set method, rather than via constructor:

```
function createBasket() {
    //pass in dependent objects
    $apiCon = $this->createAPIConnector($this);
    $basket = new Basket($this, $apiCon);
    //pass singleton config object to setter
    $basket.setConfig(Config::getInstance());
    return $basket;
}
```

Any guidance on the best approach would be much appreciated.

Thanks, James

Comment: *(related)* [Symfony Components Dependency Injection Container](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection)

Comment: Dependency Injection is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that defeats the purpose of having a singleton config object that's globally available.  The entire point is to avoid having to pass it as a parameter to every class you make.

Comment: I am trying to ensure that each class can be unit tested. I would probably rather remove the Singleton class since it's really just acting as a global holder for vars. In order to preserve the Dependence Injection in my app I need a way to ensure that these 'global' vars (and helper functions) are passed into the classes that require them. It's tempting to just leave them in global space but I am quite sure that in 6 months time I'll regret having so much stuff globally, making unit testing much trickier.

Comment: Answer given. I'll refactor the code to not be reliant on a singleton and just pass in the vars into constructors on an 'as needed' basis. Will make unit testing easier and make code easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Ive always seen them made as constants. I don't know that this is the "best" solution but I've seen this, and used it many times. Because its a const (the same is true for static vars, I would be interested to hear why one is better than the other) you don't need to instantiate the class which would probably save you some overhead if you want to be nit picky...

```
class SomeClass
{
     const MYCONS = "APIKEY or Whateva";
}
```

then in when you need to use it require the file and do something like

```
SomeClass::MYCONST //to get your config info
```

Comment: I use similar method but with interfaces instead of classes similar to Android's ContactsContract ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)

Comment: Thanks. I guess my concern is more to do with not having an 'hidden' dependency in my classes. The idea of explicitly passing these values into the constructor makes for much clearer code IMO, especially for new people working on the app. Everything that an object depends on us visible crystal-clear in the constructor args. Perhaps I'm worrying unnecessarily about these simple global vars since they really are just simple config paramaters. There are no objects or large/complex data structures. Creating a class just to hold this stuff will not benefit from OOP design away... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar method, setting everything up in a single array or file and defining it accordingly:

```
$config = array(
    'MYCONST_1'=>'myValue',
    'USER'=>'username',
    'PASSWORD'=>'y3ahr1ght'
);

foreach($config as $const=>$value){
    define($const,$value);
}
```

Comment: If I may, I will politely disagree with your code example. Using application wide constants for variables that can have different values at runtime makes it more difficult to test, if you have one test suite per class contained in a single test class, you cannot change the constant in the suite so you need some workaround like having 2 test suites for the file.  In other words: unless I missed something, if your constants are used application-wide here and there and can have multiple values at runtime in global scope, it sort of doesn't feel right in my (humble) opinion.